# stop windows 10 from dimming my laptop display when it's plugged out(other posts are outdated and not working anymore)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, display

I was looking all over the web for *stopping win10* to dim my display but only what I could found was something like this: [link 1](https://windows.gadgethacks.com/how-to/disable-adaptive-brightness-windows-10-for-maximum-screen-brightness-0163440/), [link 2](https://superuser.com/questions/1076651/laptop-dimming-display-on-dark-backgrounds), [link 3](https://superuser.com/questions/1391697/disable-brightness-change-when-charging-lenovo-ideapad), etc. but all of them are outdated.

It is no longer possible to do it in a way how link 1 is recommending, probably some updates removed that option show in the links and put it somewhere else. Does anyone of you know where that option can be found?

I really don't like doing anything with a dimmed display so my laptop is always plugged in, and that is not good for the battery.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Brightness Change when charging Lenovo Ideapad](https://superuser.com/questions/1391697/disable-brightness-change-when-charging-lenovo-ideapad)

Comment: How can an answer submitted on Jan 7th 2019 against a current version of Windows 10 be outdated?  Have you tried the registry solution?  What version of Windows 10 do you have installed?  How you handle screen brightness hasn’t really changed in Windows 10.  Any additional information should be made with an edit instead of a comment